# How to find and import only the Wikipedia infobox data into a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, wikipedia

I need to import **only infobox** data from Wikipedia into a [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) database for Turkish language, and I already found dump files on http://dumps.wikimedia.org/trwiki/20130606/. But where does the exact infoxboxdata exist?

If the infobox data is in **trwiki-20130606-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2**, how could I get only infobox data from there, because that includes much other information I think?

Comment: You will have to parse the text of articles looking for infoboxes. There is no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

Have not used this library, but may be [infobox2rdf](https://code.google.com/p/infobox2rdf/wiki/WikipediaInfoboxExtraction) is what you are looking for?.